# Share product from flutter app with django api

Tags: python, django, api, flutter

A have a website built with python/django, and i made rest api for this project.

Also i made a flutter app that uses this api.

My problem is : i need a button inside a flutter app that share a link of a product, and when someone press it(the link) , it will redirect it to open the product inside the app (not webview).

I will be so grateful to you guys.

Answer (score 0):

what's the mean of share a link of product? if you mean to show products detail in new screen you can design new stateless or stageful widget and show It with code below:

```
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
  );
```

if you want to open browser to navigate to product link you can use "url_launcher" package

Comment: i mean when i share a product from my app to whatsapp for example , i need the person who click the shared link from whatsapp, to open the app for specific product